# Vertical Margin ignored / outside of parent container

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, margin

I have a simple layout, with a container that has horizontal and vertical margin as well as a max width and height. On a computer screen, the max width and height makes it so that the margin is basically irrelevant. When I resize the window to be smaller (horizontally), the container eventually takes up the whole screen minus the margin, then gets smaller as well and the margin makes it so that there is some space between its border and the edge of the screen. However, vertically the margin is simply ignored and the container eventually goes right to the edges. I don't understand why that is happening and how I can fix it.

Here is a working example: I am using Tailwind, so that's what I used for the example as well: https://play.tailwindcss.com/t9LmsfyVfH

Edit: Here's also an image to make my point clearer:

[image]

As you can see, the horizontal margin does exist, but it's outside the window/page (or in case of the playground: container which contains the rendered content).

Comment: The container takes up a lot of space because of the following CSS: `@media (min-width: 640px)
.sm\:h-fit {
    height: -moz-fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
}
.h-full {
    height: 100%;
}
`. If you don't want the container to grow vertically on smaller screens, you should remove "h-full" from the `<main>` element.

Comment: What if I want the container to have a max width (which I set), also want it to take up this max width on smaller screens, and want it to instead be only as tall as its content on larger screens? That's why I set `h-full max-h-[560px] sm:h-fit`. Is there a different way to achieve that without the problem I described in my question?

Comment: I think you're already achieving those. What part of the functionality of the current solution are you not satisfied with?

Comment: The problem I'm having is that there is no vertical margin, or in other words space between the edge of the container and the edge of the screen when I resize the window to be small enough. I want the same behaviour that I already have with the horizontal margin to also apply vertically. Meaning that when I resize the window to be smaller, the container will have a fixed vertical margin and shrink to only fill the available space minus that margin. Edit: I meant height in my previous comment as well...

Comment: What do you mean by resizing the window? Making it smaller horizontally or vertically? I can't make the window small (short) enough vertically for the margins to matter :/

Comment: yes, making it smaller vertically. When I do that, the container fills the whole vertical space instead of having a margin between its border and the edge of the window.

Comment: @user3738870 I also edited my question and added a picture to show what I mean.

Comment: I see now, thanks! But the problem is that there is simply no more space left. The text inside has a fixed height (3.5rem because of the h-14 CSS class) so the container cannot shrink anymore.

Comment: But even if i give it a fixed width that is greater than the space required for its content and then vertically resize the window it only begins to shrink when it is right up against the edges of the window instead of respecting the margin I gave it.

Comment: Giving a fixed width doesn't matter as it only affects the horizontal aspect, and it cannot shrink vertically anymore. Isn't what you would like a container/text that fills up space vertically when it has enough and then when it doesn't, it starts shrinking?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="flex h-full items-center justify-center">
```

This is because of `h-full` class in the element. it has height 100%, that forcing element to render and squeezing the inner content. As scroll has not consider margins thus overflow is not causing, though you have given margins to the inner child.

You can override the css by simply adding custom class or parent class minimum height `.customClass.h-full{min-height: 100%;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily work around this issue by adding an empty element above the container to hold that space like `<div class="my-6"></div>` it's top + bottom margins are equal to the top margin of your `main.my-12`

https://play.tailwindcss.com/nAB8wcyXzV